# What's the virtual memory address space limitation of a Win32 application?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, virtual-memory

Below is what I understand, please correct me if i'm wrong about the 3GB part?

- a win32 application's *virtual memory address space* is limited by 4GB.
- Of the 4GB memory address space each process gets, only 2GB is actually
  available for the program to use; the other 2GB is reserved for use
  by the kernel.
- The /3GB boot option can allow some programs to use
  more memory address space.

If such an win32 application is running on a Win64 OS,

- does the above 4GB limitation of total virtual memory address space
  accessible still applies?
- does the 2GB limitation still applies?
- is the /3GB option still available?

thanks!

Comment: a must-read series of blog posts by Mark Russinovich, this one on point: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2008/11/17/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-virtual-memory/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referring to the table [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151011050456/support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/889654), we can see that a 32 bit application can have three different virtual memory limitations:

A 32 bit application linked with the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag on x64 Windows will get 4GB to itself.

A 32 bit application linked with the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag on x86 Windows with the `/3GB` boot flag will have 3GB to itself.

In all other cases, the 32 bit application will get the default 2GB/2GB app/kernel split..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [depends](http://www.google.com/search?q=win64+largeaddressaware), no.

Comment: There is no /3GB option on a 64-bit OS, but none is needed. LAA 32-bit applications can always use a full 4GB of virtual memory on 64-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: Er, not quite "always". A 32-bit app will have to be linked with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE to use 4GB of virtual memory. Otherwise it is limited to 2GB.